# SQL displaying duplicate results on page for viewing user

Tags: php, mysql

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `social_posts` . * , `social_friends` . * , `users` . *
FROM `social_posts`
JOIN `social_friends` ON `friend` = `pUID`
JOIN `users` ON `friend` = `uid`
WHERE `fUID` = '$UID' OR `friend` = '$UID'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

is supposed to select posts, user data, and verify that the user is friends with the other user. The user viewing this is defined by `$UID`, `fUID` is the friends UID and `friend` is the second friends UID.

The problem is that when this is displayed to the user, all of the users posts are showed twice, but other ones from other users are only displayed once.

PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `social_posts` . * , `social_friends` . * , `users` . *
    FROM `social_posts`
    JOIN `social_friends` ON `friend` = `pUID`
    JOIN `users` ON `friend` = `uid`
    WHERE `fUID` = '$UID' OR `friend` = '$UID'
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            $ID = $row['pid'];
            $parsed = $parser->parse($row['body']);
            echo '<div class="shadowbar">';
            echo sprintf($layout['socialViewFormat'], $row['picture'], $row['uid'], $row['username'], date('M j Y g:i A', strtotime($row['date'])), $parsed);
            $cQ = "SELECT users.*, comments.* FROM `comments` JOIN `users` ON `user` = `uid` AND `module` = 'social' AND `id` = '$ID'";
            $cD = mysqli_query($dbc, $cQ);
            while($cR = mysqli_fetch_array($cD)){
                $body = htmlentities($cR['cBody']);
                echo '<pre><a href="/ucp/uid/'.$cR['uid'].'">' . $cR['username'] . '</a><hr style="padding:0; margin:0;" />';
                echo ''.$body.'</pre>';
            }
}
```

EDIT: I've put actual values into the sql instead of using variables, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: How is this being done *"on the page"*?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek With PHP, check my edit.

Comment: Anybody have an answer?

Comment: I don't see how the SQL in the query at all matches what you are doing in PHP.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Well, I use the SQL query that is displayed in the post, in the PHP page...

Comment: I don't see such a query. The only one I see is in the variable `$cQ`. Which is clearly not the same query.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek If you look I have edited the question, as the problem I originally stated was not what I thought it was.